# run libGDX on Android error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I start using libGDX. I manage to run on desktop and work well but on Android, I get this error:

```
Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale en_US
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1314)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:991)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1063)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:954)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:787)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't understand what part is wrong android sdk, libGDX, me!!? or anything else I don't work android so match but I fully work with java se and ee .
I use IntelliJ on mac osx and testing run on emulator and real device.
my android sdk module is API 21.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189170

Comment: did you found a way to fix the bug? where is a fixed version of android-jps-plugin.jar for replacing it?

Comment: You can try 2018.1.2 EAP: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2018.1+EAP.